# How to show the multiple check box selected in wordpress?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, plugins, themes

I am showing all the child pages listed in the checkbox so that the user can check multiple child pages.

I am able to insert the check box value in the database. I am getting issues showing the selected check box and I have tried the below code but getting an error

> Notice: Array to string conversion in

I think there is some issue with this code.

```
$data.='<input type="checkbox" name="solution_innerpage_checked[]" value="'.$post->ID.'" '.checked(in_array($post->ID,$ids),$solution_innerpage_checked ,false).' ><label>'.esc_html(get_the_title()).'</label>';





function inner_childpage_list() {
    global $post;
    $solution_innerpage_checked = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'solution_innerpage_checked', true); // getting from custom fields 
    
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'solution',
        'orderby'=> 'date',
        'order'=> 'DESC',
        'post_status'=> 'publish',
        'post__not_in' => array($post->ID), //current child page id
        'post_parent'    => $post->post_parent,
    );
    $loop = new WP_Query($args);
    
    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
    $data='';
    while($loop->have_posts()): $loop->the_post();
    foreach($solution_innerpage_checked as $value){
       $ids[]= $value;
    }
      //print_r($ids); // Array ( [0] => 660 [1] => 971 [2] => 970 ) 
    $data.='<input type="checkbox" name="solution_innerpage_checked[]" value="'.$post->ID.'" '.checked(in_array($post->ID,$ids),$solution_innerpage_checked ,false).' ><label>'.esc_html(get_the_title()).'</label>';
    endwhile;
    }
    else{$data.='<div>pages are not created.</div>';}
    
    return $data;
    //wp_reset_query();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just changed this line

```
$innerpage_checked = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'innerpage_checked', true);
```

to

```
$innerpage_checked[] = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'innerpage_checked', true);
```

Its return array. Not string.

Comment: ,I have tried but nothing is happening,  I am already getting the array value $innerpage_checked. i have used foreach condition. Do you mean I have to get the string?

Comment: Which line number you are getting error?

Comment: it's showing on the wordpress file now Notice: Array to string conversion in /home/u886461233/domains/example.com/public_html/ou/wp-includes/general-template.php on line 5162

Comment: you dont have this variable anywhere in your code `$solution_innerpage_checked `

Comment: Oh.. Sorry, I have updated the latest code. Kindly check it once please